# Set columns of JTable in specified order after creation

Tags: java, swing, jtable

There is a JTable with columns in predifined order. Like

+----------------------+

|id     |    name |age |

I want to move columns in the order (for example name=0, age=1, id=2).

+----------------------+

|name     |    age | id |

How can i achive that?
JTable has method moveColumns, but unfortunately this is not enough. Assume order is strored in map:.

```
Map<String, Integer> columnOrder = getOrder();
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : columnOrder.entrySet()) {
    int columnIndex = jtable.convertColumnIndexToView(jtable.getColumn(e.getKey()).getModelIndex());
    jtable.getColumnModel().moveColumn(columnIndex, e.getValue());
}
```

This does not work, because moveColumn also moves other columns, so from docu:

```
void moveColumn(int columnIndex,
          int newIndex)
```

> Moves the column and its header at columnIndex to newIndex. The old
>   column at columnIndex will now be found at newIndex. The column that
>   used to be at newIndex is **shifted left or right to make room.**

Can i (dynamically) somehow put the columns in the exactly same order as in my map?

Comment: A `Map` has no order; try `SortedMap`.

Comment: The order is stored as Value in a map. So the map is {id=2, name=0, age=1}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying problem is of course that `Vector`, which is used in the `DefaultTableColumnModel` to store the columns and their order has no decent move support. The move is achieved as a remove and add, which triggers the "move left or right" behavior.

You can however use this knowledge to simply move the columns in the correct order (from lowest index to highest index).

Starting from

```
|id | name |age |
```

to

```
|name | age | id |
```

can be achieved by first moving `name` to index 0. This will result in a

```
|name|id|age
```

vector. If you then move age to index 1, it will do a remove first

```
|name|id
```

followed by an insert at index 1

```
|name|age|id
```

By making sure the element is always moved to the left side of its original position, you know how the shifting will behave.

Of course this depends on an implementation detail, but write a quick unit test to support your assumptions and use those implementation details (or write your own `TableColumnModel` ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

- [JTables RowSorter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) has implemented [public abstract List getSortKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html#getSortKeys%28%29)
- but [why reinvent the wheel by @Darryl Burke](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/08/29/multisort-table-header-cell-renderer/) and [about SortKeys](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/?s=DefaultTableHeaderCellRenderer)

EDIT

> No, i don't need to sort rows, i need to put the colums in order

- have look at [TableColumnModel#moveColumn(int columnIndex, int newIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html#moveColumn%28int,%20int%29)
- [example about `Stack<TableColumn>` could be here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10089138/714968)

Comment: No, i don't need to sort rows, i need to put the colums in order

Comment: exactly, so the columns (id, name, age) -> (age, name, id) a

Comment: see my edit, inc good way (my view) to helt arrays of TableColumns in the Stack, sure you can use any alternative :-)

Comment: @AvrDragon: You can have `Value` implement `Comparable` or supply a `Comparator`, but you'll still need a `SortedMap`.

Comment: @trashgod no, i don't need a SortedMap. The sorting order is stored as Values. The order of how is sorted order stored itself in insigninicant:3

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), "Some map implementations, like the `TreeMap` class, make specific guarantees as to their order; others, like the `HashMap` class, do not."

Comment: @trashgod the entries in his map are indeed unordered, but the order is stored in the map. So he can loop over all entries, and determine for each column (=key) the corresponding index (=value). So he doesn't need an ordered map. He will have to go through the whole map before finding which column must be at index 0 however (same for other indices)

Comment: Ah, an in-place [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), of sorts. :-) Thanks!